# Oracle date extract and concatenate

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to take a date (`dd-mon-yyyy`) and change the year based on a user input. How do I extract the day and month and add the year while keeping the format?

For example, it is currently `01-JAN-2015`, and the user wants it to be `01-JAN-2016`. I currently am doing:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM contract_year) || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM contract_year) || '2016'
FROM table
WHERE program = programid
```

And my output is `112016`, but I want `01-JAN-2016`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean something like `select  to_date( to_char( sysdate, 'dd-mm' )||-'2016' , 'dd-mm-yyyy' ) from dual;` ?

Comment: I just need to take the day and month from the current variable and concatenate it with a user-entered year...would your suggestion do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT to_char(add_months('01-JAN-2015', 12*1),'dd-MON-yyyy') -- replace 1 with n where n = years
from dual
```

If you want to add use given year to current date/month, use this

```
      with your_table as(
      select '01-JAN-2015' as contract_year from dual
      )
      select to_date(substr(to_char(contract_year),1,7)||'2017','DD-MON-YYYY') from your_table
```

If your are not seeing output as required, it means that you have to change your client setting. Try running this in SQL Plus window.

Comment: The user will be entering a year not a number or years to add. For example the date might be 2014 and the user enters 2017.

Comment: Edited the answer. Replace `2017` with user input date. Also add convert the output to `to_char` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Combine to_date and to_char:

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(contract_year,'dd-mm-') || '2016','dd-mm-yyyy')
FROM table
WHERE program = programid
```

Comment: It looks like that worked! I have to test it in our program first to be sure, but running the query it gives the results I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me whether `contract_year` is a date or a string.

If it's a date:

```
select to_char(contract_year, 'DD-MON-') || '2016'
  from table
```

If it's a string in the format `DD-MON-YYYY` then:

```
select to_char(to_date(contract_year, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-') || '2016'
  from table
```